# How can I import a mercurial repo (including history) into another mercurial repo as a subdirectory, without using subrepos?

Tags: mercurial

This sounds kind of complex, so let me explain:

Project_A has lived for some time within its own Mercurial repository. Project_A is now getting folded into a new super project, Super-Project_B.  Super-Project_B also has a mercurial repository. We would prefer if Project_A were not a subrepo, but instead just a normal child, but we also don't want to lose the history.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Yeah.  Use the convert extension to move projectA down one directory level:

```
hg convert --filemap filemap.txt projectA projectA-redone
```

where your `filemap.txt` has this line in it:

```
rename . projectA
```

(that dot might be a slash but I don't think so).

That will give you a new repo, projectA-redone, that has all the history of A though all the changesets will have different hashes since their content (paths) have changed to get "projectA" in front of all of them.

Then you go into Super-Project_B and do a `hg pull -f /path/to/projectA-redone`.  You need the `-f` because otherwise you'll be told that the repos are unrelated since they have no changesets in common.

Finally you'll do a `hg merge` in Super_project_b which should have no conflicts (unless you already had a projectA directory, in which case you should've picked a different name or `hg remove`d it first).

After doing that B will have all of A inside the projectA subdirectory and all history will be intact.

Comment: was it a dot or a slash that worked.  I thought it was a slash but the help says to use a dot if you're going the other way (rename projectA . to move it to top level) so I guessed that.

Comment: @Ry4an It was dot. Still works perfectly. I first had to enable the convert extension in my mercurial.ini as well

Comment: @Ry4an: Works! But how to do if i want projectA to be imported under a particular branch "xyz" of Super-Project_B? The above solution imports it to default branch.

Comment: Found it! Add `--branchmap branchmap.txt` to conversion, with branchmap.txt containing `default xyz`

Comment: For TortoiseHG users the **convert** extension is enabled in File->Settings in TortoiseHG Workbench

Comment: For windows users, the convert extension must be added to mercurial.ini under the current user's directory - c:\Users\currentUserName\mercurial.ini